# How to know which part of regex matched?

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-group

regex= `(i.*d.*n.*t.*)|(p.*r.*o.*f.*)|(u.*s.*r.*)`
string to be matched= `profile`

Now the regex will match with the string. But I want to know which part matched.

Meaning, I want (p.*r.*o.*f.*) as the output

How can I get do this in Java?

Comment: You can test your regex here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can check if which group matched:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(i.*d.*n.*t.*)|(p.*r.*o.*f.*)|(u.*s.*r.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("profile");
m.find();
for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + ": " + m.group(i));
}
```

Will output:

```
1: null
2: profile
3: null
```

Because the second line is not null, it's `(p.*r.*o.*f.*)` that matched the string.

Comment: For this, I will have to store the regex parts in a hashMap so that I can retrieve what the regex is for the corresponding non-null output. Looks like more computation. However, if I could get (p.*r.*o.*f.*) directly as the output, it would be better. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, It seems like you can distinguish those subpatterns with the first letter. If the first letter of the match is 'p', then it will be your desired pattern. Maybe you can construct simple function to distinguish these.

Comment: If you need to do a second pattern matching after the first pattern matching, then I'd suggest you should reconsider how you do the first one to begin with.

Comment: I can always construct a function to isolate each regex part and find which part matches. I was wondering if there was some in built function to perform this task?